# A c++ class include a static member with the same type of itself. Why this pattern?

Tags: c++, class, static

I inherited a project from a former colleague, and I found these code snippets (and some similar ones in SO questions: [can a c++ class include itself as an member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-member) and [static member object of a class in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874317/static-member-object-of-a-class-in-the-same-class))

```cpp
// Service.h
class Service
{
// ...
public:
    static Service sInstance;
    void Somememberfunc();
//...
};

// Service.cpp
#include "Service.h"

Service Service::sInstance;

void Service::Somememberfunc()
{
//...
}

// Main.cpp
#include "Service.h"
void Fun()
{
    Service &instance = Service::sInstance;
    //...
    instance.Somememberfunc();
    //...
}
```

However, I did not find any explanation on when to use this pattern. And what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the member is a static, so it's part of the class, not of instantiated objects. This is important, because otherwise you would be trying to make a recursive member (since the member is part of the object, it also contains the same member and so on...), but this is not the case here.

The best pattern to describe this is: **global variable**. The static member is initialized before main() and can be accessed from any part of the program by including the header file. This is very convenient while implementing but becomes harder to handle the more complex the program gets and the longer you have to maintain it, so the general idea is to avoid this. Also, because there is no way to control the order of initialization, dependencies between different global variables can cause problems during startup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I say that this pattern is similar to static class in c# if the constructor is private.

Answer (score 1):

Static member is roughly a global variable in the **scope** of the class.

Static members have also the advantage of visibility access (`public`/`protected`/`private`) to restreint its usage (file scope might be an alternative).

That member might be of type of the class.

Global are "easy" to (mis)use, as they don't require to think about architecture.

BUT (mutable) global are mostly discouraged as harder to reason about.

Acceptable usages IMO are for **constants**:

- as for a matrix class, the null matrix, the diagonal one matrix.
- for Temperature class, some specific value (absolute 0 (O Kelvin), temperature of water transformation(0 Celsius, 100 Celsius), ...)
- in general NullObject, Default, ...

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern. For example, you can use it to store your app configurations. And then you can easily access configurations anywhere(globally) within your app.

Comment: this might be misleading. The class in OPs code is by no means a singleton

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: it might be, there are lot of not shown code. but anyway, that doesn't answer OP.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes might be, my point is just that OP is asking "what is the patttern when a class has a static member of its own type" and pedantically that alone is not the singleton pattern

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for your reply. If the constructor is 'private', can it be a singleton?

Answer (score -1):

This is often used in the singleton design pattern
Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: same comment here: this might be slightly misleading, because the class in OPs code is no singleton